# Sharing Sharepoint News with Digital Signage Screens

Tags: external-list

We have an intranet site where we carry employee news, announcements and vacancies.

We also have screens for our front line staff running ScreenCloud.

I was hoping to output RSS feeds from our lists and expose these through Screencloud but they are not visible unless logged in, which isn't possible through Screencloud.

Does anybody have any suggestions about how to expose the content externally?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

as an alternate approach, you can create a dummy IIS web site with an anonymous access. Create a custom page that exposes the list content in to RSS or in a feed with required format. here the code can even run on elevated privileges via SharePoint object model.

To expose externally, you can get a domain name mapped to the static IP. Assign this static IP in the IIS bindings of the web site with SSL certificate.

Comment: We operated on Sharepoint Online through O365 - is this still an option?